# Let $s \in \mathbb{N}$ be some positive integer: How many combinations for $v \in \mathbb{N_0}^d$ so that $\sum^d_{j=1} v^2_{j} < s$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, vectors, combinations, balls-in-bins

I have a combinatorial problem. I want to find out how many possible combinations exists for a vector $v \in \mathbb{N_0}^d$ so that the squared $l_2$ norm is smaller than some positive integer value $s$.

Problem:

Let $s \in  \mathbb{N}$ be some positive integer.
Let $V = \{v \in \mathbb{N_0}^d | \sum^d_{j=1} v^2_{j}  < s\}$.
What is $|V|$.

Comment: Like in this **almost** equivalent issue of the number of integer coordinate points in the open ball of $\mathbb{R^d}$ with radius $\sqrt{s}$, you can get estimations but don't expect an exact formula. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/310549/88984)

Comment: Let $|V|=f(s,d)$, then $f(s,d)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{s}\rfloor} f(s-i^2,d-1)$, $f(0,d)=0$, $f(s,0)=1$